# rsync - write delta (new data) to new file

Tags: python, bash, rsync

I have a growing web server log file that rotates once a week, and I need to feed 1 hour worth of logs to some python script. So, rsync is the solution, right?

I know that rsync would transfer (add) only new (changed) date in file. But how do I make it write new lines from remote log (form last time it did so an hour aga) to a separete file for inspection?

So, the difference from normal behaviour is that it does not append new (changed) lines to local file, but just writes the difference to a separete one.

Comment: I'm pretty sure `rsync` is not the tool for this job - it is concerned with keeping a set of files synchronized, not with inspecting the files to determine specific semantic content and processing only specific portions of the files based on arbitrary rules. I would suggest modifying the `python` script to isolate only the lines it is interested in, instead.

Comment: but how to do it remotely? I mean without downloading whole file first.

Comment: By all means, use rsync to keep a local copy of the log, downloading only the new content. What you can do to improve your python script is remember the previous size of the log. When you open the log, you can `seek` to the previous "eof" and start reading from there.